# Promoted pawn keeps a pawn in the diagram

Tags: xskak

As shown in chess diagram 2, after f7xe8B+ the pawn at e8 is not promoted to a Bishop.
However, in diagram 3 the pawn has changed to a bishop.

What did I do wrong?

[image: Chess diagrams]

Here is the source code:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{a4}
    \usepackage[german, ngerman]{babel}
    \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[LSBC4,T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{chessboard}
    \usepackage{xskak}
    \setboardfontencoding{LSBC4}
    \newskaklanguage{german}{KDTLSB}
    \skaklanguage[german]       
    % set size of printed area
    \textheight 23.5cm
    \topmargin  -0.5cm
    \footskip 12mm                      
    \begin{document}        
    \styleB
    \newchessgame[id=A1,
    setfen=1n2r1n1/bp1ppPpb/6k1/1p2q3/5P2/2pK4/1r6/2B5,
    moveid=1w
    ]
    % Display starting position
    \chessboard[smallboard]%
    % Enter game
    \hidemoves{1. f7xe8=L+ Kh6+ 2. f4f5+ g7g5 3. f5xg6+}%

    % Show board after white's first move
    \chessboard[smallboard ,setfen=\xskakget{nextfen}]%
    \quad \xskakget{opennr}\xskakget{lan}%
    \\
    The white pawn reaches e8, but it is not promoted as a bishop.

    %increment move id
    \xskakset{moveid=1b}%
    % Show board after black's first move
    \chessboard[smallboard ,setfen=\xskakget{nextfen}]%
    \quad \xskakget{opennr}\xskakget{lan}%
    \\
    Now the pawn at e8, is promoted correctly.
    \end{document}
```

Comment: I am not sure, if the package provides for an automatic `promotion` of figures?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer In that case, shouldn't the pawn never get promoted?

Comment: @cfr: My statement was probably misleading: I meant that the package probably accepts a move like f7ex8=L+ but it is not automatically transferred to a promotion as desired, but to be honest: I've never used the package so far

Comment: That's a bug. The fen are stored too early, before the board has changed the promotion piece. The black black promotion has the same problem. I will have to look into it. But it shouldn't be too difficult to repair it.

Comment: I have uploaded an new version to CTAN which will hopefully resolve the problem and spread around soon.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you, I installed your new version and promotion works fine now.